# Oracle Database installation stuck at 'Starting Oracle Net Configuration Assistant'

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, database-administration, dbca, oracle-net-services

I am installing Oracle database 12c (12.1.0.2.0 - Enterprise Edition ) in windows 10 and it stuck at "starting 'Oracle Net Configuration Assistant' " at step 8 of 9 (83%) for than 4 hours. Please suggest any solution to fix this problem.

Here are some last log file details:

```
Setting up 'Enterprise Edition Options 12.1.0.2.0 '
Setting up 'Oracle Database 12c 12.1.0.2.0 '
Saving inventory
Starting 'Prepare for configuration steps'
Starting 'Prepare for configuration steps'
Completed 'Prepare for configuration steps'
Starting 'Oracle Net Configuration Assistant'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think some pressing `Alt` + `Tab` combination to provide you to see the 
[image: dbca popup alert]

and click on it to end the installation( i suppose, popup window should stand behind to hold the wizard ).

By the way, i think, you will see

```
Database mounted 
Database opened
```

infos in `postDBCreation.log`. and check if

```
SQL> select status from v$instance
```

gives `OPEN`, resulting that There's no problem.